# Finding the inverse of a matrix whose components are functions of t

Tags: linear-algebra

I am to find the inverse of the following matrix:

A(t) =  \begin{bmatrix}
        t & t^4\\
        0 & 5t \\
        \end{bmatrix}

and after I used this formula to find the inverse

[image: inverse formula]

The inverse of A(t) is:

\begin{bmatrix}
        t^{-1} & -0.2t^2\\
        0 & 0.2t^{-1} \\
        \end{bmatrix}

I am working with WebWork and it keep telling me my answer is incorrect.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the website, it looks to me like you have the right answer. You should try emailing the professor.

Comment: your calculation are right, send WebWork away

Comment: your WebWork may have been programmed to recognize specific form of the answer and can't see that you give the same thing. Try to write the fraction 1/5 instead of 0.2, perhaps 1/t instead of negative power etc... Another option - appeal to your professor.

Comment: Note that your matrix is not invertible if $t=0$, so maybe you have to take cases to get the right answer .